# SignalR hub scalability issue

Tags: .net, signalr, signalr-hub

We have a SignalR hub called StatusUpdateHub. This hub is updated by a .NET client called HubClient. This client will be (in production) called about 1000 times per second by multiple users for different transactions. Here is the client code:

```
public static class HubClient
{
    private static readonly string statusUpdateUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StatusUpdateUrl"];
    private static readonly HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(statusUpdateUrl);
    private static readonly IHubProxy hub = connection.CreateProxy("StatusUpdateHub");

    internal static void UpdateBrowser(long transactionId)
    {
        connection.Start().ContinueWith(task => hub.Invoke("UpdateTransactionStatus", transactionId)).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted && task.Exception != null)
            {
                // log error
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When this code is called with 100 concurrent users it is working fine but when we increase the number of concurrent users to 250 then we are seeing the following error:

> Unexpected error in UpdateBrowser: System.InvalidOperationException:
>   The connection has not been established.     at
>   SignalR.Client.Connection.SignalR.Client.IConnection.Send[T](String
>   data)     at SignalR.Client.Hubs.HubProxy.Invoke[T](String method,
>   Object[] args)     at SignalR.Client.Hubs.HubProxy.Invoke(String
>   method, Object[] args)     at
>   Application.Services.HubClient.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_0(Task
>   task1) in c:\Build\Work\Application\Services\HubClient.cs:line 20
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InvokeFuture(Object futureAsObj)
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Let us know how we can make the code more scalable?

Comment: Did you by any chance have a limit on simultanious connections on the server?

Comment: Are you also monitoring memory consumption throughout the runs?  Are you.  I'm curious to know what the trends are that you are seeing with increased # of users connected/disconnected. I was seeing some unreleased memory in our app, and wondering if it was due to SignalR or something else.

Comment: @Stilgar we have not set any limit. What setting should I change in machine.config?

Comment: @ElHaix will ask my performance test team to provide me the stats and will let you know.

Comment: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Performance - the default is pretty high so I doubt this is the problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If that's the method being called 1000 times per second, you shouldn't be calling `connection.Start()` every single time.

Open the connection only once, then just invoke methods on it.

**Edit**, what I mean is, at the very least, make your code do something like this:

```
internal static void UpdateBrowser(long transactionId)
{
    lock (connection) 
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Disconnected){
            connection.Start().Wait();
        }
    }
    hub.Invoke("UpdateTransactionStatus", transactionId).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted && task.Exception != null)
        {
            // log error
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

By default .NET allows 2 concurrent connections outgoing from client apps and 10 from ASP.NET apps. If you want to increase this number then set the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx to a bigger number. See if that helps.